# Ruby code not getting interpreted while the routing is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this very strange behavior, where the basic routing in my application is working fine sometimes and sometimes not , and somehow in my view files, the ruby code inside of <%= ...... %> is not rendering at all. This part( the one inside <%= %> )  just shows blank. I know that the control comes here because if I write any string outside of these delimiters , then it shows up on the page.

On the routing front,  problem I am having is that my controller for create is going to index. I was following the example tutorial from http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html

I am using ruby version 1.9.3p194 and rails version 3.2.6

My source files are as follows.

**routed.rb**

```
resources :posts  
match '/create', :to => 'posts#create'

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

**index.html.erb**

```
In posts index file

<% form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>  
  <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br />  
  <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "44x6") %><br />   
  <%= submit_tag("Update") %>  
<% end %>
```

**create.html.erb**

```
<%= debug(params) %>
<%= render :partial => "message_form" %>
<%= render :partial => @posts %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
buddy, here I am in show now .
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "I am in Posts#index"
    @posts = Post.all(:order=>"created_at DESC")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def show
    puts "I am in Posts#show"
  end

  def edit
    puts "I am in Posts#edit"
  end

  def new
    puts "I am in Posts#new"
  end

  def create
    puts "I am in Posts#create"

    @post = Post.create(:message=>params[:message])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html {redirect_to posts_path}
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Message failed to save"
        format.html {redirect_to posts_path}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I type `http://localhost:3000/posts/create`, it shows me "buddy, here I am in show now ."  which is the  the rendering for show.html.erb and does not execute any ruby code

When I type `http://localhost:3000/posts`, it shows me "In posts index file " , which is rendering for index file but no part of the ruby code is executed

Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `=` sign in this line in posts index and that's why the form is not rendered.

This line

```
<% form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
```

That should fix the 2nd problem at least.